# Coordinates of buttons in chess board

Tags: c#, chess, coords

I made dynamic board which looks like chessboard. Is there any way to get coords of some button I click? Example: If I clicked on last button, label text would be: "Column 5,Row 5".

[image]

Comment: Start from here: the Click event has a `sender` argument, which actually is the button which is clicked. Cast it to a `Button`, use whatever information you have associated  from the `Tag` property etc.

Comment: This is probably good for a learning project but keep in mind that this approach (using a separate button for each square) represents a poor, resource-wasting design that you shouldn't use in general.

Answer (score 0):

you set a tag for every object, use a suitable object instead of a simple integer.

E.g, you can use `Tuple<int, int>` :

```
btn.Tag = Tuple<int, int>.Create(row, column);
```

or

```
btn.Tag = new Point(row, column);
```

if you use an old version of .Net framework not supporting Tuple

in click event for every button in your chessboard, retrieve tag value for the sender button

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `d` is an int (and global):

```
int tag=(Button)sender.Tag;
int row=tag/d;
int col=tag%d;
```

As an example, the 19th button in your 5x5 grid, would have a Tag of 18 (you started with 0).  Then 18/5 is 3. and 18%5 is 3.  Which would be Row 3, Column 3 (Assuming you start numbering your rows and columns with 0 as well, otherwise just add 1 to each).  If this doesn't make sense, 18 divided by 5 is 3 with a remainder of 3.  In integer math, `/` gets the dividend part, and `%` gets the remainder which neatly converts to your rows and columns.

If you need to store more data than just the row/column in a button, you might consider using a custom class and assigning that to the Tag property.  You can then retrieve it on click and you'll have all the information ready for you.